# Raspberry Pi does not start

Tags: raspbian, power, boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1 + Raspbian 3.18 Debian Wheezy inside.

Everytime I plug in the power, it requires a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> to boot, and the screen stays inactive (no signal).

After the first <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>, the restarts are normal and don't require keyboard anymore.

Obviously this is making my device impossible to deploy!!

Anybody experienced this? How can I solve this?

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking. Is it just that there is no display? Have you tried either unplugging all USB devices or using a powered USB hub? What about a different display?

Comment: Well, with the same mouse, keyboard and monitor, there were no problems under other operative systems. Under that distribution of Raspbian i experienced that problem... I am not using any USB hub or special device. After the CTRL+ALT+DEL the system start to boot normally... I dont have another display for testing :/

Comment: Have you a freshly built Raspbian image and tried booting from that?  Just to be sure that the software isn't having a problem ... if it still won't boot from there we will have eliminated one potential source of error and can focus on the hardware characteristics.

Comment: I did it about five times... Ive checked the SHA-1 key for the Raspbian Debian Wheezy 3.18, claimed to be compatible with the RPi2. I think i will just change to another OS or plainly another platform...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Change your card.

Kingston Micro SD HC - SDC4/8GB is unreliable with current version of Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1 + Raspbian 3.18 Debian Wheezy (2015-04-03).

Check this [link](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) for a list of suitable SD cards.